# How to correctly link libgit2 to C program using cmake?

Tags: c, windows, cmake, libgit2

First of all, i'm just a newbie in a CMake magic. And i just want to link libgit2 to my simple C program in CMake way ([FindLibgit2.cmake](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2-backends/blob/master/CMake/FindLibgit2.cmake)).
As i understand from [cmake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake%3aHow_To_Find_Libraries) my CMakeLists.txt should looks like that:

```
project(libgit2test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
# This variables should be setting up externally, i know - i show them just for example
set (LIBGIT2_LIBRARIES "<path to directory with git2.lib and git2.dll")
set (LIBGIT2_INCLUDE_DIR "<path to libgit2/include>")

find_package(Libgit2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBGIT2_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LIBGIT2_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

In my simple program i just call a couple of simple `libgit2` functions and get this:
`WARNING: Target "libgit2test" requests linking to directory "<libgit2 build directory>".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.`

I think the problem is here: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} {$LIBS})`
I try to change it to `git2`, but than i just get `can not open file`.
What i'm doing wrong?

P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 compiler, Qt Creator to create CMake project, and successfully build `libgit2` with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
set (LIBGIT2_LIBRARIES "<path to directory with git2.lib and git2.dll")
set (LIBGIT2_INCLUDE_DIR "<path to libgit2/include>")
```

These variables should be set by `find_package(Libgit2 REQUIRED)`.

Comment: I'm getting this from CMake: "CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND."

Comment: If you have your library/headers in custom path, point CMake to it by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of problem: variable `LIBGIT2_LIBRARIES` must point to lib file itself, not the directory of it (debug/release).
However, setting up manually this variables looks like wired. I want to find more "automatic" way to find `libgit2` - if one exists.

Comment: The intended way to use `find_package()` is to let it find libraries/headers itself. You should only give it hints, if your files are located at some custom path.

Comment: "Hint" is `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as i understood. But how to "ask" CMake to search library binaries *not* in `lib` directory?
P.S. Thanks for answer/

Comment: Why would you want such thing? CMake searches in `${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib` and `${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}` for find libraries.

Comment: @arrowdodger Because i'm built `libgit2` into a `build/Debug` directory. So, you consider such path as non-standard? And i should use `libgit2/lib` one.

Comment: Yes, this path is non-standard. Common pathes are `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` and some other for Unixies.

Comment: @arrowdodger I'm build libgit2 manually because i need the latest version. So, relative path of libraries and include files should be `libgit2/lib` and 'libgit2/include', without intermediate directories like `build`, `debug` etc.?

Comment: You should separately build and install libgit2 info custom prefix (`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`) and then point `find_package()` in your CMake project to it. This is proper way to do it.

Comment: So, if i will install libgit2 using `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/lib ..` and specify `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib` - all things should working nice?
But i also need to use CMake under Windows. It's `/usr/lib` analogue is `Windows/System32`?

Comment: I'd rather install libgit into `/home/somewhere` for Unix and anywhere in Windows. Note that in Windows application automatically looks for .dll's in it's directory and working directory, so you don't need to put libgit2.dll into System32 dir.